# Google Map API without credit card

Tags: android

I have problem with, using google API as it ask me to type credit card number (master card, Visa card). so how can I get google map API ?

Comment: Please visit the following link to know how to ask a good question https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Provide more detailed information on your question.

Answer (score 1):

Google API are not for free. The only way is to pay for it ;)

Comment: here you find more information [link](https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/user-guide/)

Comment: "As of June 11, 2018, you must enable billing with a credit card and have a valid API key for all of your projects." Well then, how do you deal with creating a website with maps API for client in case he's going to give you one-time payment? You make him create his own account, or..?